# How to get git to use an ssh (rsh) transport other than "ssh"

Tags: git, ssh, rsync, rsh

Is it possible to get git to use something other than "ssh" as the ssh program?  Rsync has a -e option for this purpose, and other interfaces where rsh or ssh can be used as the transport.  The particular use case I have is chaining the ssh connection via a bastion host, as direct ssh access to the host from which I'm cloning / pulling is not allowed by the firewall.

The best solution I've come up with so far is to create a directory with a single executable called "ssh" in it, and put that directory at the start of my PATH.  The contents of the "ssh" file is:

```
#!/bin/sh
# If we were being clever we'd look at where we were and just snip that
# off the path.
export PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin
exec ssh bastion.example.org ssh "$@"
```

This works, but the approach has a number of drawbacks.

Note that the GIT_SSH environment variable doesn't do what I'm after, as you still have to create a script and reference that.  Whereas with rysnc's -e option I can do

```
rsync -e 'ssh -K bastion.example.org ssh' ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying to configure git to use another program, you can configure ssh itself:

On the `~/.ssh/config` file, add a new `Host` section

```
Host git.example.org
  Username myusername
  ProxyCommand ssh bastion.example.org "nc git.example.org 22"
```

Then, you just need to point your remote to the "git.example.org" host.

Also, if you are using OpenSSH >= 5.4 and don't want the dependency on netcat on the server, you can use SSH's [netcat mode](http://blog.rootshell.be/2010/03/08/openssh-new-feature-netcat-mode/) instead:

```
Host git.example.org
  Username myusername
  ProxyCommand ssh bastion.example.org -W "git.example.org:22"
```